# Convert arbitrary bytes to any lossless common image format

Tags: image, encoding, imagemagick

How do I convert a file with up to 320k of bytes into an image with with 1, 2, or 3 bytes (any will do) of color?

I'm wanting to show off how small my 1980's era application is by representing 100% of the 320k of data as a bitmap image printed onto my project card.

I *know* the data won't look like anything but noise, but that's OK. I just want to be able to say: "That's it - those pixels uniquely represent every byte in this application!"

It'd be cool if there was a "2D barcode" app that does this, but after an hour of searching I couldn't find one that had the capacity and was implemented (plenty of papers.)

Comment: Can imageMagick be coerced into doing this?

Answer (score 3):

> Can imageMagick be coerced into doing this?

Absolutely!

Let's start be generating a program file with size of 320k.

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=myProgram.blob bs=1000 count=320
```

*YMMV*

**Gray approach.** One channel 8-bit image.

```
cat myProgram.blob | \
   convert -size 500x640 -depth 8 -format GRAY GRAY:-  gray_output.png
```

[image: gray_output.png]

**Color approach.** Three channel 8-bit image.

```
cat  myProgram.blob | \
   convert -size 500x213 -depth 8 -format RGB RGB:- rgb_output.png
```

[image: rgb_output.png]

You'll need to do a bit of math to determine the image sizes, but that's easy.

```
total_bytes = [number of channels] * width * height
```

> I know the data won't look like anything but noise, but that's OK. I just want to be able to say:
>
> > "That's it - those pixels uniquely represent every byte in this application!"

A year or so ago I had the same issue. I needed a quick visual checksum to "at a glance" determine if data-blobs differed.

And so, I created [vizsum](https://github.com/emcconville/VizSum). In no way lossless, or mathematically safe, but prettier on the eyes.

```
 cat myProgram.blob | vizsum -sha1 -bilinear visual_checksum.png
```

[image: visual_checksum.png]

---

**Update** just for fun.

Here's a quick C program using the [MagickWand API](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php)

```c
// program2img.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <wand/MagickWand.h> // Or <MagickWand/MagickWand.h> if using IM 7.x.x

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    FILE
        * fd;

    const char
        * input,
        * output;

    unsigned char
        * buffer;

    long
        program_size,
        program_area,
        program_width,
        program_width_data,
        program_height,
        col,
        row;

    MagickBooleanType ok;

    // Collect input / output
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <input> <output>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    input = argv[1];
    output = argv[2];

    // Open input for reading
    fd = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open `%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Get size of input
    fseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_END);
    program_size = ftell(fd);
    fseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    // Roughly calculate size of output image.
    program_area = program_size / 3;
    program_width = sqrtl(program_area);
    if (program_width < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to generate image width\n");
        return 1;
    }
    program_width_data = program_width * 3;
    program_height = program_area / program_width + 1;
    if (program_height < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to generate image width\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Boot ImageMagick
    MagickWandGenesis();

    PixelWand * color;
    MagickWand * wand;

    color = NewPixelWand();
    wand = NewMagickWand();

    PixelSetColor(color, "BLACK");
    MagickNewImage(wand, program_width, program_height, color);
    color = DestroyPixelWand(color);

    buffer = malloc(program_width_data);

    // Iterate over input and build image line-by-line
    for (row = 0; row < program_height; ++row) {
        col = fread(buffer, 1, program_width_data, fd);
        // Add padding (might need to double check this logic)
        while (col < program_width_data) {
            buffer[col++] = '\0';
        }
        MagickImportImagePixels(wand,
                                0, row,
                                program_width, 1,
                                "RGB", CharPixel, buffer);
    }
    fclose(fd);
    // Save image output.
    ok = MagickWriteImage(wand, output);
    if (ok == MagickFalse) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to save output `%s'\n", output);
    }
    wand = DestroyMagickWand(wand);

    MagickWandTerminus();
    return 0;
}
```

Which can be compiled with

```
clang `MagickWand-config --cflags --libs` program2img.c -o program2img
```

And used

```
./program2img mySmallProgram output.png
```

[image: output.png]